# Are there such good C compilers that fortran is becoming a redundant language?

Tags: c++, c, fortran

Just wondered, as I'd always considered Fortran's use to be in supercomputing. However, I often hear C compilers can make C as fast as Fortran, so is it's use limited?

Also, if this is true what are the fastest C compilers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11):

Argh!  No, no it doesn't.  And in related news, Fortran growing some OOP/polymorphic stuff doesn't obsolete C++, Erlang doesn't render Haskell superfluous, python hasn't killed bash scripting, PHP doesn't obviate the need for javascript, and mysteriously, nothing has killed off Java, etc, etc, etc.  There are a bazillion programming languages out there for a reason -- there is a set of programmers that finds them good tools for specific jobs.  You don't have to like them for that to be true.

C is, fundamentally, a systems programming language.  It is wretchedly painful to write anything like computational science stuff in it.   C++ is better because it's richer, but suffers critically from the fact that it doesn't have multdimensional arrays as a first-class type (no, it just doesn't, ok?), and all of technical computing relies critically on multidimensional arrays.   The lack of a single standard multidimensional array package for C/C++ makes it very difficult to write optimized libraries for that language, and once you commit to one package you have to use their data structures throughout.   Python suffers from the same problem, and will do so until Numpy becomes part of Python core.

Fortran, for all its flaws, is the only language out there designed specifically for scientific programming.  It allows python- or matlab- like array operators and slicing, and that can a scientific programmers life easier.  Even then, lots of scientific programers don't like fortran; they prefer the toolsets or libraries available in other languages.  And that's ok.

And just to fend off your next question -- no, we don't have to all agree on editors, either.

Comment: "[C++] suffers critically from the fact that it doesn't have multdimensional arrays as a first-class type". The last bit is true, but what are the consequences? Neither is `std::complex<>` (also a library type), and nobody complains about that either.

Comment: @MSalters: The problem is that in a non-trivial project where you may want to use a handful of 3rd party libraries, you'll have to deal with a handful of mutually incompatible multidimensional array classes and shuffle data between them in some way. std::complex, OTOH, is in the standard library so world+dog doesn't go about reinventing it all the time. Then again, if you need, say, sparse arrays, Fortran doesn't help you, and you have the same problem; in that case C++ might even be a better choice due to templates and operator overloading making user-defined array classes easier than Fortran

Comment: ..and now fortran has operator overloading and parameterized types (not templates, but the main use of them here would be for different kinds of reals) so can do this, too.  But yes, I agree that sparse stuff is harder and you see the same thing (eg, Petsc).   The absense of even dense matricies in C/C++ comes up in other things, too -- in almost any MPI question for C on SO that deals with multidimensional arrays, part of the answer always comes down to showing the C programmer how to create contiguous multid arrays.  That should just be something your programming language does for you.

Answer (score 2):

Fortran has some properties that allow faster programs. Esp pointers stop the compiler from optimize code (and arrays are passed as pointers in C - and arrays are THE datastructure in HPC). Problem here is that two pointers can alias, in fortran this can not happen. In new C99 this problem is reduced, when good written, as you hint the compiler with `restrict`, that such alias can not happen.

But as there is very much old fortran code in the companies fortran never will get obsolete in near future.

Comment: I find it funny every time a 12 year old standard is called new.

Comment: so would you say fortran is still faster?

Comment: It's not that much about fortran vs C being faster, it's about the already written code being faster. It's going to take some considerable effort for people to rewrite their finely tuned fortran code in C.

Comment: @Null Set: You know you are getting old, when...

Answer (score 2):

Fortran isn't going away any time soon.  There is too much Fortran code:  fast, reliable, well-tested routines for doing all sorts of things, and programs that may be less well-designed but which work and would be difficult to rewrite in C.

Moreover, Fortran as a language is designed around high-performance computing, and has no little barriers to optimization, and Fortran compilers are usually designed for high-performance computing.

Comment: I don't think the question is about rewriting existing Fortran code in C.  The question as I see it is, what potential performance benefits does the latest Fortran standard offer over the latest C standard, for new code?

Comment: Available libraries are a very valid reason for choosing one language over another, in fact they usually factor into the decision more than raw performance. When the libraries are also likely to be the best performers, you have a win-win.

Answer (score 2):

Fortran 90 / 95 / 2003 / 2008 are higher level languages than C.    I'd pick C for embedded or device programming, and modern Fortran for scientific programming.

Answer (score 1):

Two words. Legacy code. There will still be plenty of Fortran around in 20 years, just as there will be plenty of COBOL. And my heart goes out to those who have to maintain it.